# read table cell value on mouse click by javaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am using ASP.NET MVC application. In razor code, i am displaying table of some record from database and what i want to get record id "FeeZoneID" from cell value on mouse click on delete link in last td and alert in javascript... so that later on with ID i can perform required function....

```
        <table id="FreeZone_ViewAll_Grid">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeeZoneID)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FeeZoneDescription)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Functions
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td id="record_Id">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FeeZoneID)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FeeZoneDescription)
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <a href="#" class="DeleteEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" onclick="load_DeleteFreeZone_page(this.document.getElementById('record_Id').innerHTML)">Delete-FeeZone</a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>
```

### javaScript

```
 function load_DeleteFreeZone_page(record_id)
{
    alert("delete "+record_id);
}
```

Comment: This is invalid html.  The id value is suppose to be unique.  I suggest that you append the `item.FeeZoneID` to it.

Comment: Yes that is right.  Also if you have a class associated with you click, then you will be able to retrieve the ID using jquery.

Comment: many thanks i have tried as your method and it work too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend storing the data on the element and attaching the event handler using javascript (best practice).

**Sample Markup:**

```
<a class="DeleteEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" data-id="@(item.FeeZoneID)">Delete-FeeZone</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.DeleteEntry_Icon').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  alert(id);
});
```

This will attach the click function to all elements with the `DeleteEntry_Icon` class, but will use the data from the specific element that is clicked.

Inline js (onclick in the html) has never been good practice. Read through some of these results: [**Why is inline JS bad?**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)

Answer (score 3):

you can use @(val) in html

```
<a href='link' onclick='func(@(item.id))'>text</a>
```

and in foreach,this will render to

```
<a href='link' onclick='func(1)'>text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Razor you have a loop that builds the rows in the table. The only thing wrong here is that you have multiple td elements all with the same id of "record_id". This makes it difficult for your JavaScript to interact with the cells, and it will typically always use the first one. Instead, try to give each element a unique id. I recommend:

```
<td id="record_@(item.FeeZoneID)">
```

The data attribute from m59's example is a good way to do it.

```
 <a href="#" class="DeleteEntry_Icon Hyperlink_Text" data-id="@(item.FeeZoneID)">Delete-FeeZone</a>
```

The inline JavaScript isn't necessary because we will grab the id and value with separate event-based JQuery.

```
@section Scripts
{

<script>

JQuery(document).ready(function(){ //when the document is ready
    jQuery('.DeleteEntry_Icon').click(function(event){ //when a cell is clicked
        event.preventDefault; //don't let the browser try to follow the link
        var feezone = jQuery(this).data('id');

        alert("delete "+feezone);
        //do your other JavaScript here

        return false; //prevent older browsers from following the link
    }); 
});
</script>
}
```